# find random number between -7 and -12 with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, random

I got this javascript code that returns a random integer number between `1` and `10`.

I got a problem making it return a  random number between `-7` and `-12`.

You gotta bail me out of this one, please...

```js
const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;
console.log(`Random value between 1 and 10 is ${a}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference between -7 and -12 = 5.

First, change your code to give a random number between 0-4 (or 1-5) instead of 1-10.

After that, subtract 12 from the outcome.

Comment: Tried it like this on PlayCode and its returnig -5, very functional

Comment: `const a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1)) + 1;let k=a-12;
console.log(`Random value between 1 and 10 is ${a}`);console.log(k);`

Comment: I mean your code is returning values outside the expected range...-8,-9,-10,-11

Comment: @CoderTimothy, yes you didn't follow all instructions. You are still looking for a number between 1 and 10 in the first step, not 0-4. Also, try some kindness for someone trying to help you. Your first comment is extremely rude.

Comment: i apologize if i sounded rude but i had of intentions of sounding so...Your code will work if i replace as you said , thanks

Comment: @CoderTimothy If you didn't intend it I misunderstood your intentions! I apologize for that =) good luck!